# How to show iris(some says shutter) in Camera while capturing image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, camera

I have implemented camera in iPhone and taking images and save it in PhotoAlbum.
Now what i want is when i save one image and make button enable for taking second image i want iris to be shown in between.So that it feels excatly like Camera functionality of iPhone.
How i do that please give some suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apps like Stachematic and Zombiematic actually got away with using this private API ...

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:0.3];
animation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
[animation setType:@"cameraIris"];
[cameraView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```